# React JS color picker inside form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been struggling with this all day. Really new to react so apologies in advanced.

I'm trying to use [react-jsonschema-form](https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form) to create form from json with [react-color](https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color).

This is what I have now:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {ChromePicker} from 'react-color';
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";

const ColorPicker = (props) => {
    return (
        <ChromePicker
            color={props.value || false}
            value={props.value}
            onChange={(event) => {
                props.onChange(event.color)
            }}
        />
    )
}
const schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "base": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Global settings",
      "properties": {
        "line-height": {
          "title": "Body line height",
          "type": "number"
        },
        "background-color": {
          "title": "Body background color",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "font-color": {
          "title": "Body background color",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
const uiSchema = {
    base:{
        "background-color":{
            'ui:widget':ColorPicker
        },
        "font-color":{
            'ui:widget':ColorPicker
        }

    }
}
export default class GeneratorForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleChange(data) {
            console.log(data)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Form schema={schema}
                  uiSchema={uiSchema}
                  //onBlur={this.handleSubmit}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  //onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                  onError={log("errors")}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Simple form with two colorpickers. And the colorpicker works great, except in the handleChange, formData for that field is empty. It's like the value isn't assigned. I've searched for similar topics, somethings similar with datepicker[3](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1051) and that gave me an idea to make it simple (had some crazy code, custom class component and so on).

So the question is, how to pass a value from color picker to form value?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [the Docs for react-color](http://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/). You aren't handling the `onChange` event correctly. It should be:

```
const ColorPicker = (props) => {
    return (
        <ChromePicker
            color={props.value || false}
            value={props.value}
            onChange={ color => {
                props.onChange(color)
            }}
        />
    )
}
```

`event.color` doesn't exist. The `onChange` handler will get two arguments, `color` and `event`.

Comment: omg I love you. This was actually very stupid mistake (like typo or sth). Funny thing I was looking at the console.log and didn't noticed it's not the color property I need... It's probably because of so many hours I've spent on this. This is my first react contact ;-) Also this works `onChange={(event) => props.onChange(event.rgb)}`. Thank you!